# Unexpected behaviour when with HTML Table rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I am creating a dynamic table generator, and during testing, I found that the following generated HTML gives an unexpected layout in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am expecting a 2x3 table, with top corner merged with the left cell in middle row, and and the middle row right cell merged with the bottom right cell but instead i ended up with a 2X2 grid

side note, even if I provided a height on the css or the row/cell attribute; doesn't change layout of the resulting table.

p/s i don't intend to use this for layouts; i just will like to idiot proof my codes from unintended effects from weird layouts such as this

Edit:

Expected:

```
|------|-------|
|      |       |
|      |       |
|      |-------|
|      |       |
|      |       |
|------|       |
|      |       |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

Result:

```
|------|-------|
|      |       |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
|      |       |
|      |       |
|------|-------|
```

Edit 2:
added CSS

```
table { 
   border: 2px solid #000000;
   padding: 10px;
}
td { 
   border: 2px solid #FF0000;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
}
tr {
   border: 2px solid #00FF00;
   padding: 10px
}
```

I also tried:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; height:200px"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; height:100px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; height:200px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #FF0000; height:100px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the layout you described: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6xU/. Could you show the CSS as well?

Comment: sure.. try this css in the question

Comment: I am getting the desired layout, When you populate the table it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry.. filling it in.. but you have gotten it.. it looks like the key is tr.height... with it, it fixes everything.. (td height does jack..)

Comment: This was really helpful... if you want, do fill in the answer so that i can upvote you.. (and people know how noobish I am :) )